# how to simullate inheritance when using functions instead of classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a base class that has some functionality(snapshot 1), I also have 2 child classes that extend from the base class and use a common method(snapshot 2). I know it is very object oriented approach :). Due to the intent of encapsulating I have to switch to use the IIFE and module approach( snapshot 3). I am struggling to understand how can I inherit `bonus` function from the `BaseDepartment` class into my `IT` and `Accounting` classes? I came up with the approach of creating in stance of `BaseDepartment` class and frankly don't like it since it creates and instance everytime. I know JS is not inheritance based and prototype based instead. But I am not sure how to solve this problem with or without prototyping.
Thank you in advance

```
class BaseDepartment{

    constructor(){this.basePay = 1000};
    bonus(bonus){return this.basePay+bonus};
}
```

```
class IT extends BaseDepartment{
    somePrivateFunction(){
        //this function should be private and encapsulated, not able to do so with classes have to use module approach
    }
    bonus(){return super.bonus(200)}
}

class Accounting extends BaseDepartment{
    
    bonus(){return super.bonus(300)}
}
```

```
let IT = (function (){
    let baseDepartment = new BaseDepartment()
    function somePrivateFunction(){
        //this function is encapsulated now and not accessble to outside
    }
    return{
        bonus: function (){return baseDepartment.bonus(200)}
    }

});

let Accounting = (function (){
    let baseDepartment = new BaseDepartment()
    return{
        bonus(){return baseDepartment.bonus(300)}
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't quite get why you don't want to use classes which are especially introduced for occasions like this one.

Comment: Folks here might be able to better help if you backed up and talked about the actual programming problem you're dealing with rather than jumping to a fairly unusual attempt at solving it.  Functions don't inherit.  They can call other functions at will or you can break smaller pieces of functionality into shared functions that multiple other functions can use.  And, perhaps also explain why you can't use classes for this.

Comment: btw ... the function based approach/part does not show/utilize a single IIFE (which the OP claims going to use)

Comment: @jfriend00 it's due to this concern - Due to the intent of encapsulating I have to switch to use the IIFE and module approach. I updated the question to be more clear why I cannot use classes

Comment: @VLAZ  it's due to this concern - Due to the intent of encapsulating I have to switch to use the IIFE and module approach. I updated the question to be more clear why I cannot use classes

Comment: Any properly written js-file can serve as a module. Any properly written class can be part of whichever properly written kind of js-module. Is the OP aware of the meaning of the terminology being used? Does the OP have a basic understanding of the techniques being used?

Comment: @Alex why is [this](https://jsbin.com/ruxipucefu/1/edit?js,console) not an option? Or, you know, use modules which are basically this.

Comment: "*Due to the intent of encapsulating I have to switch to use the IIFE and module approach*" - like Peter said, there are no IIFEs and no modules in your third snippet. Also it's not quite clear what encapsulation you are talking of, or what you're trying to achieve there. Is it something about that `somePrivateFunction`? You can simply remove that anyway since you're not calling it anywhere.

Comment: You have not clearly described the actual problem to be solved here.  You say *"intent of encapsulating"* is the reason to not use classes.  Sorry, but that doesn't mean anything to us yet and actually sounds like it's probably misguided since classes can be fully encapsulated just fine.  I don't think anyone can help you until you stop assuming a solution and describe the actual problem here.